# MySQL Query dependent on table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got few tables in mysql.

```
table1 = students:
Id,
Name,
sName

table 2 = subjects:
Name
```

and for every name in subjects there is a table witch id and grade

Is there a way to make a query in MySql witch would print me something like that ? How can i do it ?

```
Name,sName,subjectName1,subjectName2...
John Miller A,A,B ...
```

I am sorry I am new here but it seems that someone added code to my question for me.

Also I am not sure how can i explain  my question better.

I want to make a visual table that shows students and their grades and I am trying to do it as simple as possible.

I am trying to do that with JOIN  but i am stuck at trying to use subject name in query not sure how to do that.

---

The subjects table is only to create columns in output table

```
Name | SecondName | Physics | Math | ...
John | Miller     |    A    |  B   |
```

Thats what i want

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you want to get some help here you should first of all show what you have already tried.

Comment: After the edit also, I can't understand the question clearly

Comment: No 'id' in the subjects table, just 'Name'? And what are the fields in the third table you mention? (best show all three as SHOW CREATE TABLE output)

Comment: I believe that you need something similar to this answer, take a look and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9668036/89435

Comment: It does sound to me like what you're looking for is a `PIVOT`.  That is possible to do, but it's complicated because it's not exactly proper relational algebra especially without an aggregate function.  As far as the database is concerned it's a display issue, and therefore not the database's problem.  Usually it's recommended to do that sort of thing in the application instead of the database.